# Ios Swift Toggle underline of attributed string

Tags: ios, swift2, toggle, underline, nsmutableattributedstring

I hav written two fuction to Add underline to a String and remove underline :

I want to toggle underline with a button.
So how do I check if NSMutableAttributedString has underline attribute :

```
func addUlnTxtFnc(TxtPsgVal :String) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let TxtRngVal = NSMakeRange(0, TxtPsgVal.characters.count)
    let TxtUnlVal = NSMutableAttributedString(string: TxtPsgVal)
    TxtUnlVal.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value:NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: TxtRngVal)

    return TxtUnlVal
}

func rmvUlnTxtFnc(TxtPsgVal :NSMutableAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let TxtRngVal = NSMakeRange(0, TxtPsgVal.string.Len())
    TxtPsgVal.removeAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, range: TxtRngVal)

    return TxtPsgVal
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check by calling the function `.enumerateAttribute(attrName:, inRange:, options:, usingBlock:)` on the `NSMutableAttributedString` you get in as the parameter:

```
func rmvUlnTxtFnc(TxtPsgVal: NSMutableAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let TxtRngVal = NSMakeRange(0, TxtPsgVal.length)
    TxtPsgVal.enumerateAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, inRange: TxtRngVal, options: .LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { attribute, range, pointer in
        if attribute != nil {
            TxtPsgVal.removeAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, range: range)
        }
    }
    return TxtPsgVal
}
```

Also, you can shorten your first function to a single line:

```
func addUlnTxtFnc(TxtPsgVal: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    return NSMutableAttributedString(string: TxtPsgVal, attributes: [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue])
}
```

---

As an aside, your code does not conform to the [Swift style guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) proposed by the Swift community.